# How to find all entries containing a word as a whole word only?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Toad for Oracle and I have a Table called CO_EXCEPT_TEXT_LG.
The Table is similar to the below:

| Deviation | Action |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | UNLOCK PHASE |
| 2 | UNLOCKED PHASE |
| 3 | UNLOCK |
| 4 | To UNLOCK PHASE |

I'm trying to pull all entries that have the word 'UNLOCK' as a whole word only. (In this case, this would be entries 1, 3 and 4.)

I have tried the following so far:

1. `WHERE ACTION = 'UNLOCK'`: gives Entry 3
2. `WHERE ACTION LIKE 'UNLOCK'`: gives Entry 3

(I think LIKE without wildcards essentially functions like '='. Correct me if I'm wrong!)

3. `WHERE ACTION LIKE '%UNLOCK%'`: gives Entries 1,2,3,4
4. `WHERE ACTION LIKE 'UNLOCK%'`: gives Entries 1,2,3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the word boundaries you want are spaces, here is one way to do it with `like`:

```
where ' ' || action || ' ' like '% UNLOCK %'
```

We could also use a regex:

```
where regexp_like (action, '(^|\s)UNLOCK(\s|$)')
```

... where `^|\s` means: either the beginning of the string (`^`) or a space (`\s`) - while `$` represents the end of the string.